# Helm plugin install from Azure devops repo url

Tags: azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I have my helm plugin code pushed to a Azure devops repo and I want other developers to install the helm plugin with the following command

```
helm plugin install https://dev.azure.com/xyz/_git/my-helm-plugin
```

I am getting a Cannot detect VCS error when I do this. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Helm version 3.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your command, you are using the Azure Repo source.

The cause of this issue is that the repo URL is not correct.

You can try the following format

```
helm plugin install https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/my-helm-plugin.git
```

In addition, you may encounter authentication issue. You can also add  credential in the url.

For example:

```
helm plugin install https://PersonalAccesstoken@dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/my-helm-plugin.git
```

Comment: Is there any special setting to enable access with the .git extension?  The URL https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_git/my-helm-plugin.git does not work for helm plugin install as well as git install.   For helm install I get the error - remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier my-helm-plugin.git does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.

Comment: Got it working by renaming my repo to my-helm-plugin.git explicitly.  Git version - 2.34.1